# Why is the Compute Throughput’s value different from the actual Performance / Peak Performance?

Tags: cuda, gpu, profiling, nvidia, nsight-compute

I want to build a roofline model for my kernels. So I  launch the ncu with the command

> ncu  --csv --target-processes all --set roofline  mpirun -n 1 ./run_pselinv_linux_release_v2.0 -H H3600.csc -file ./tmpfile

The `roofline set` collects enough data to build the roofline model. But I can't figure out the meaning of each metrics clearly.

The `Compute(SM) Throughput` is collected by the metrics `sm__throughput.avg.pct_of_peak_sustained_elapsed` which is `0.64%`.  And I think it is the percentage of Peak Performance. But when I divide the `Performance(6855693348.37)` by the `Peak Work`(5080428410372), I get `0.13%`, which is much lower than `0.64%`.

Besides, I want to collect the `FLOPS` and `memory usage` in my kernel, not their throughput.

So my question is:

1. What is the real meaning of `SM Throughput` and `Memory Throughput`? Are they the percentage of `Peak Work` and `Peak Traffic`?  By the way, `Peak Work` and `Peak Traffic` are `Peak Performance` and `Peak Bandwidth of DRAM` respectively, right?
2. To get the real `FLOPS` and `memory usage` of my kernel, I want to multiply the `Compute(SM) Throughput` and `Peak Work` to get the `real time Performance`. Then I multiply the `real time Performance` and `elapsed time` to get the `FLOPS`. So does to memory usage. Is my method correct?

I have been searching for this question for two days but still can't get a clear answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the answer from this question: [Terminology used in Nsight Compute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63403203/terminology-used-in-nsight-compute?rq=1)
In short, the `SM Throughput` and the `Memory Throughput` is the maximum of a series of metrics respectively. So I just tried to understand their meanings by their name, which is totally wrong.

By the way, the correct way to collects FLOPS and memory usage of your model is in this lab: [Roofline Model on NVIDIA GPUs](https://gitlab.com/NERSC/roofline-on-nvidia-gpus/-/tree/roofline-hackathon-2020/)
The methodology this lab

> Time:
>
> sm__cycles_elapsed.avg / sm__cycles_elapsed.avg.per_second
>
> FLOPs:
>
> DP: sm__sass_thread_inst_executed_op_dadd_pred_on.sum + 2 x
> sm__sass_thread_inst_executed_op_dfma_pred_on.sum +
> sm__sass_thread_inst_executed_op_dmul_pred_on.sum
>
> SP: sm__sass_thread_inst_executed_op_fadd_pred_on.sum + 2 x
> sm__sass_thread_inst_executed_op_ffma_pred_on.sum +
> sm__sass_thread_inst_executed_op_fmul_pred_on.sum
>
> HP: sm__sass_thread_inst_executed_op_hadd_pred_on.sum + 2 x
> sm__sass_thread_inst_executed_op_hfma_pred_on.sum +
> sm__sass_thread_inst_executed_op_hmul_pred_on.sum
>
> Tensor Core: 512 x sm__inst_executed_pipe_tensor.sum
>
> Bytes:
>
> DRAM: dram__bytes.sum
>
> L2: lts__t_bytes.sum
>
> L1: l1tex__t_bytes.sum